# How to modify/create values in XML files using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, xml

I would like to know if is it possible to modify/create values in XML files using PowerShell. Basically I'm interested in:

- Modify values in the XML file or create them if they don't exist (i.e. I need to search the item, create if not exists and modify the value)
- Deal with different XML syntax in the same XML file like those ones:

Syntax 1:

```
<settings>
  <setting id="Location2" value="Barcelona, Spain"/>
  <setting id="Location2id" value="zmw:00000.1.08181"/>
</settings>
```

Syntax 2:

```
<settings>
    <musicplayer>
        <crossfade>0</crossfade>
        <queuebydefault>false</queuebydefault>
    </musicplayer>
</settings>
```

Syntax 3:

```
<settings>
    <skinsettings>
        <setting type="bool" name="skin.confluence.HomepageHideRecentlyAddedVideo">false</setting>
    </skinsettings>
</settings>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

PowerShell fully supports dealing with XML files.

For example, if we take the first blurb you supplied and just paste it into an XML file named `settings.xml` in folder "C:\blah", you could get the ID of each setting as such:

```
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content C:\blah\settings.xml
$myXML.settings.setting.id
```

Which returns:

```
Location2
Location2id
```

And

```
$myXML.settings.setting.value
```

returns:

```
Barcelona, Spain
zmw:00000.1.08181
```

If we replace the XML file contents with the blurb you provided in Syntax #2:

```
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content C:\blah\settings.xml
$myXML.settings.musicplayer.crossfade
```

returns:

```
0
```

To read `crossfade`, change it (to 2), and save back:

```
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content C:\blah\settings.xml
$myXML.settings.musicplayer.crossfade = 2
$myXML.Save("C:\blah\settings.xml")
```

*Edit after comments:*

To change the XML elements themselves (as in the Barcelona example) is a little trickier, because you're editing the XML structure itself, not the data it contains.

```
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content C:\blah\settings.xml
$myXML.settings.ChildNodes.Item(0).value = "New York, USA"
$myXML.Save("C:\blah\settings.xml")
```

For the Skinsettings example, try something like:

```
$myXML.settings.skinsettings.setting."#text" = "true"
```

Check out these resources:

- [The Scripting Wife Learns to Use PowerShell to Work with XML](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/25/the-scripting-wife-learns-to-use-powershell-to-work-with-xml.aspx)
- [Use PowerShell to Parse an XML File and Sort the Data](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/26/use-powershell-to-parse-an-xml-file-and-sort-the-data.aspx)
- [How to update an Xml Element value using PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/9b9fab3a-2335-4dfe-b1bd-2df62b17b2cd/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read your suggestions and I'm trying to update the value of id="Location2" in the first blob from Barcelona to New York without success. The same with the third blob (trying to change to "true"). How can I find/modify these kinds of values?

Comment: I'm trying selecting the node I want to change using the following `$MyXML.SelectSingleNode("/settings/skinsettings/setting[@type='bool' and @name='skin.confluence.HomepageHideRecentlyAddedVideo']")` but, how can I change the value from "false" to "true".

Or how can I create a node like this if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Check out my edit. I added some more info. :)